# Is it possible to use another conditional expression inside a conditional expression?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I was wondering about the "? :" operators in C. Can one use the conditional operator inside another conditional operator like this?

```
int a = 0;
a == 1?a += 1:a == 0?a += 2:a = 3;
```

This is a very bad example, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: I wouldn't use ternary with side effects...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There is a sequence point at `?`.

Comment: yes you can use by using proper parenthesis

Comment: `a = 3` --> `(a = 3)`

Comment: Yeah but why, using ternary statements in this way just obfuscates code.

Comment: @Trepid - Fastest code doesn't mean the shortest, most cryptic, and unreadable code. Optimizing compilers are a lot smarter than most people believe, and writing *readable* code also helps the compiler understand it, so it can produce fast machine code.

Comment: @BoPersson Awesome advice. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, C allows things like `1?1?1?1:1:1:1`. Or if you want to make it extra clear that the programmer has no common sense, do this:  `1??!1?1??!1?1??!1?1??!1:1??!1:1??!1:1??!1`.

Comment: @TrepidClaw0601 The first thing to realize here is that compact source code has no relation what-so-ever with efficient machine code. `?:` is never faster than `if-else`.

Comment: @TrepidClaw0601 It is an alternative way of writing `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, like this :

```
int a = 0;
a == 1?(a += 1):((a == 0)?(a += 2):(a = 3));
```

It is the same as writing :

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 1)
    a += 1;
else
    if (a == 0)
        a += 2;
    else 
        a = 3;
```

which is much more clear to read and understand.

Comment: Indeed @Jean-FrançoisFabre, editing my post with this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you must use parenthesis like so:

```
a == 1?a += 1:(a == 0?a += 2:a = 3);
```